# C# TcpClient cannot connect to simple python TCPIP listener connection refused even though docker instances can communicate

Tags: c#, python, docker, networking, tcpclient

I have two docker containers starting on the same machine. One is running a python app which has a simple `TCP/IP` listener. The other is a `C#` application which attempts to send data using the `TcpClient`.

The `TcpClient` errors at the connection stage stating

> Connection refused

However if I access the `C#` docker containers, I can telnet directly on to the `python` containers without error.

I am testing this using a windows machine and have made sure to disable the windows firewall. These two docker containers are running `mono:latest` and `python:3.7-slim`, the port `1080` is exposed. The logging shows that the containers IP address is resolving correctly and it is unclear to me what is preventing a connection.

```cs
public static bool Send(byte[] message)
{
    int convertedPort = -1;
    try
    {
        convertedPort = Convert.ToInt32(TiePort);
        AppLogger.Info("Connecting to:" + TieHost + ":" + convertedPort);
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

        IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(TieHost).AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint (ipAddress, convertedPort);
        AppLogger.Info("About to connect to :" + ipAddress);
        // fails here to connect
        client.Connect(ipEndPoint);
        AppLogger.Info("Client connected");

        client.Close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        AppLogger.Error(e.Message + e.StackTrace);
        return false;
    }
}
```

```py
class ListeningThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, context, host, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.is_running = True

    def run(self):
        self.sock.listen(5)
        while self.is_running:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(60)
            try:
                data = client.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    context.received_data = data
                else:
                    raise error("Client disconnected")
            except:
                client.close()
                return False
        client.close()
        return False

    def terminate(self):
        """raises SystemExit in the context of the given thread, which should 
        cause the thread to exit silently (unless caught)"""
        self.is_running = False
        self.raise_exc(SystemExit)

    def create_listener(context):
        try:
            context.ListeningThreadObj = ListeningThread(context, "0.0.0.0", 1080)
            context.ListeningThreadObj.start()
```

I expect the `python` listener to accept the `c#` connection and there is nothing obvious blocking it.

Comment: Unrelated: Put `client.Close()` in a `finally` block or use `using`.

Comment: I'd use some tool like Wireshark to verify what is going on on the line. Maybe it's just the wrong port. (Yes, you know it's the right one ... been there, done that: make _sure_ it is.)

Comment: You say “pod”; are you actually in a Kubernetes environment?  What are the values of `TieHost` and `TiePort` in the client?  Can you include relevant details like your `docker run` commands and/or `docker-compose.yml` and/or Kubernetes YAML files?

Comment: Sorry meant container not pod, corrected question